# Create hölder continuous function

Tags: calculus

Let $0<\lambda\le1$, $C>0$. Suppose that $f$ is defined on ${\mathbb R}^n$ and satisfies the estimate $$\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|\le C\left|x-y\right|^\lambda$$ for all $x,y\in{\mathbb R}^n$.

Is this called Hölder continuous?
If it is, can anyone give an example of a function $f:{\mathbb R}\to\mathbb R$ as in Hölder continuous such that 
with $\lambda=1/2$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $0$, $1/3$ and $1$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the definition is right, $λ=1$ is also called Lipschitz-continuous.

The standard example for Hölder $1/2$ is the square root function $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$, be free to add a sign factor. To get your singular points, put a polynomial with those points as roots under the root.

Answer (score 0):

One such example is

$$f(x)=\operatorname{Re}\left( \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x-\dfrac{1}{3}} + \sqrt{x-3} \right)$$

Note that the real part is zero when the argument of square root is negative.

A real-variable notation would be
$$f(x)= \sqrt{x^+}+\sqrt{(x-1/3)^+} + \sqrt{(x-3)^+}$$